# Как лучше всего заменить некое выражение в строке? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть некоторая строка типа:
"Привет <% name %>. Некий текст <% text %>"

На выходе нужно получить (с переменных)
"Привет Вася. Некий текст текст"

Каким способом правельнее всего это сделать?

Comment: `const name = 'Вася', text = 'текст', str = 'Привет ' + name + '. Некий текст ' + text; console.log(str);`

Comment: @MedvedevDev к сожалению такой вариант не подходит так как приходит строка, в которой нужно только заменить некоторые выражения

Comment: через `replace` можно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: а, ну тогда да, реплейс наверное самый адекватный вариант

Comment: А как правельнее всего заменить с помощью replace? Ведь могут например написать лишний пробел и т.д. типа <%user  %>

Comment: там регулярка, а у регулярки можно указать что может не быть пробела. однако если это шаблонизатор, то следует иметь соглашение по правильному оформлению

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = "Привет <% name %>. Некий текст <% text %>";

console.log(s.replace(/<%\s*(\w+)\s*%>/g, (m, n) => ({
  name: "Вася",
  text: "и ещё текст",
}[n] || m)));
```