# Как заменить несколько слов в строке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, как заменить несколько слов в строке, например есть текст:

"для переноса {{numb}} строки завершите предыдущую {{button}} пробелами"

надо сразу заменить слова {{numb}} и {{button}}, как регуляркой можно сразу 2 слова заменить?

Comment: Дублирует https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723012/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-jquery

Comment: String.replace в помощь. Два раза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var s = "для переноса {{numb}} строки завершите предыдущую {{button}} пробелами";

console.log(s.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g, (m,n) => ({
  numb: 'в конце',
  button: 2
}[n] || m)));
```